# Clarifications about CPU working: as the functions to get the operands are physically generated?

Tags: cpu

I ask patience to help me to have clarity because I tend to equivocate between **formal rappresentation** like

`like operator is a token
bit
it is determined which operation is to be performed and how to get the   operands, according to a function whose domain consists...`

and what is **physically-electronic-logic rappresentation** CPU elements operation like

```
CPU configuration signal
Registers
pulses
```

about some with respect to certain specific technical processes.
The cause is related to mixing high bit, operator, operand when it working like functions.

I don't what mean for 'value' - what is this 'value' ? A logic state, adressing mode? i don't understand why operands may as a constant value

`Often, one group of bits (that is, a "field") within the instruction, called the opcode, indicates which operation is to be performed, while the remaining fields usually provide supplemental information required for the operation, such as the operands. Those operands may be pecified as a constant value`

What it mean 'pulses' ? I don't understand well the connection of bit like rappresentation and its physical state version. This pulses are generated about what electronic component ?

`the control unit produces the sequence of pulses on each control signal line required to implement that instruction`

I really don't understand if this functions are math or logic states about operand assembly (decode).

`Operand Assembly: once the word has been taken from memory, it is determined which operation is to be performed and how to get the operands, according to a function whose domain consists of the operating codes (typically the high order bits of the word) and the co-domain consists of the microprogram to be executed`

But..as these functions are generated to get the addresses from which electronic element ? Registers ? Addressing Mode ? I don't understand if it refers about instruction sets, a part of the architecture or if one process?

I don't understand well this electronic logic passage. Hardwired ? Multiple clock pulses ? Is there some link to understand better this ?

`In some CPU designs the instruction decoder is implemented as a hardwired, unchangeable circuit. In others, a microprogram is used to translate instructions into sets of CPU configuration signals that are applied sequentially over multiple clock pulses. In some cases the memory that stores the microprogram is rewritable, making it possible to change the way in which the CPU decodes instructions`.

what is configuration signals physically-logic ?

```
is used to translate instructions into sets of CPU configuration signals
```

But it is done by the ALU or not?

I don't understand Microcode

`The microcode is a layer of hardware-level instructions that implement higher-level machine code instructions or internal state machine sequencing in many digital processing elements`

Operand: numerical data on which the product is an arithmetic or logic

I understand mean of high-order bit and high word
http://www.gamedev.net/topic/414290-please-explain-high-and-low-order-bitword-terminology/

I understand what is *word* 
http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/word

and is ok also operand definition (wiki) but I don't understand WHAT THEY ARE like LOGIC_PHYSICALLY ? 
**How they are made to logical-physical level?**

I don't understand why defined bit length of a word is equivalent to the width of the computer's data bus so that a word can be moved in a single operation from storage to a processor register.

Comment: I think you may need to split this up into many questions.  The StackExchange format is not designed to handle asking 9 or 10 questions all at once.

Comment: "pulses" may be the result of a very awkward translation of a word similar to "clock" from some non-English language to English. Alternatively, chickpeas, lentils and beans are pulses. Don't ask me what this has to do with a CPU.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you have two texts here, one talking about CPUs in the most clumsy way imaginable, and one sounding like a quite reasonable text book, and you can't get the terms of that clumsy text explained by the text book.

I suggest you read that text book, and that text book alone, because the other text isn't going to help your understanding at all. Something like "the control unit produces the sequence of pulses on each control signal line required to implement that instruction" sounds like someone with no understanding at all trying to hide behind big words.

Comment: `the control unit produces..` is take from wiki, [WIKI](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Microprocessor_Design/Instruction_Decoder)
`
`An operator is a token which acts on a pair of data (or on a single data), said operands..` is take from [HERE](http://www.bo.cnr.it/corsi-di-informatica/corsoCstandard/Lezioni/07Operatori.html)

Comment: My Italian is a bit rusty, but I'm quite sure the second link has nothing to do whatsoever with a CPU.